Why does Google Scholar omit the publishers and editors in chapter citations?
I've noticed, at least in my own research, it seems to regularly do this with few exceptions.
When trying to use Google Scholar's cite feature on a chapter of an edited volume, it gives a reduced version of the citation.
For example: searching "Garden Hunting and Food Sharing during the Mississippian Period in the American South" gives this range of citations across all of GS's available styles:

It seems to treat it as a journal article, almost. I'll focus on Chicago for this part: everywhere I can read about citing the chapters of edited volumes tells me the citation should look like this:

Peres, Tanya M. "Garden Hunting and Food Sharing during the
Mississippian Period in the American South." In Food Provisioning in
Complex Societies: Zooarchaeological Perspectives, edited by Levent
Atici and Benjamin S. Arbuckle, 171. Boulder: University Press of
Colorado, 2023.

Sometimes, there are exceptions. Searching and citing "Ocean cultures: Northwest Coast ecosystems and Indigenous management systems" gives this:

Mathews, Darcy L., and Nancy J. Turner. "Ocean cultures: Northwest
Coast ecosystems and indigenous management systems." In Conservation
for the Anthropocene ocean, pp. 169-206. Academic Press, 2017.

Is there some new, extra, highly specific rule out there that I'm unaware of?

It's an automated process that scrapes other sources.
Sometimes Google's tools guess correctly.
Other times they do not.
Pages such as https://docs.pkp.sfu.ca/google-scholar/en/ explain how Google Scholar works.
However, only Google truly knows how Google Scholar works because it is closed source.
I don't think we (the general public) can provide much more details to your question.
